# AJAX inserting content instead of redirecting to lock page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an if statement that checks if user time logged in is more than 10 seconds, it should redirect the page. it does so without AJAX but it only runs the script after the page is reloaded.

```
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/account/Dashboard' || '/account/Dashboard/?Login=Success')
    {
      $time = time();
      $uid = $userRow['user_id'];
      //$auth_user->auto_timeout($time,$uid);
      ?>
     <div id="auto-lock"></div><?php
    }
```

Then I have this js script to run auto-lock.php

```
  <script>
  var refresh = setInterval(
  (function () {
  $("#auto-lock").load("../../inc/ajax_content/auto-lock.php");
  }), 10000);
 </script>
```

auto-lock.php

```
if ($time - $userRow['auto_timeout'] >= 10)
{
  $auth_user->redirect("../../account/LockScreen/?Lock=true");
 }
```

Now instead of it redirecting to the Lock screen it simply includes the lock screen within the `/account/Dashboard` page:

[image: With Ajax Refresh loads into Dashboard instead of redirecting to /LockScreen]

^^^^^ With Ajax Refresh loads into Dashboard instead of redirecting to /LockScreen

Am I perhaps doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are using

```
 <script>
  var refresh = setInterval(
  (function () {
  $("#auto-lock").load("../../inc/ajax_content/auto-lock.php");
  }), 10000);
 </script>
```

load will fetch the data from auto-lock.php and load the html into div `#auto-lock`. To redirect you need to use this script

```
 <script>
  var refresh = setInterval(
  (function () {
  window.location.replace("../../account/LockScreen/?Lock=true");
  }), 10000);
 </script>
```

It will redirect user to auto-lock.php page.Just saw your full code there is no need of auto-lock.php file if you want to lock screen after 10 seconds only js will do the job.

Comment: will give it a try now, totally forgot to add the content in autolock.php. I have updated the question with my autolock.php content

Comment: I think it is better the previous way because I am going to execute a session_destroy() function to kill the session as well.

Comment: Sure you can do that too. :) @JamesBond